# Batch Scripting: Manipulate text file input and output

Tags: batch-file, printing, text-files

I'm trying to create a script to delete all printers on a given computer by name that have a certain word in their name.

Here's my script so far:

```
Cscript %WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnmngr.vbs -l
:: lists printers

Cscript %WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnmngr.vbs -l >>%USERPROFILE%\printers.txt
:: outputs to text file

set LINECOUNT=0
for /f "delims==" %%I in (%USERPROFILE%\printers.txt) do (
set /a LINECOUNT=LINECOUNT+1    
)

echo There are like %LINECOUNT% lines in this document. >>%USERPROFILE%\printers.txt

type %USERPROFILE%\printers.txt | findstr /b /c:"Printer name PRINTERtobeDELETED" >>%USERPROFILE%\filter.txt

FOR /f "tokens=*" in (%USERPROFILE%\filter.txt) do STUFF THAT DELETES THE FIRST 13 CHARACTERS, GOD. (OR FIRST TWO WORDS/TOKENS, W/E) >> %USERPROFILE%\trimmer.txt
```

Basically, my biggest problems going out from here are these two:

1. I have a list of printer names prefixed as "Printer name PRINTER", where I want to simply isolate the name, so I need to delete the first two words or 13 characters
2. I need to create a loop feeding each line of a text document to my code that will delete a printer.

Thanks for reading this, and have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

If you have yet the list of printers to delete in `filter.txt`, and the content of the file is something like

```
Printer name here goes the printer name
-1-------2----3----4----5----6------7---- = number of token in the line
```

then all that is needed is to discard the two first tokens (space delimited) and get the remaining. So we will ask for token number two and the rest of the line (the name of the printer) inside another token

```
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ("%USERPROFILE%\filter.txt") do (
    cscript "%WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnmngr.vbs" -d -p "%%b"
)
```

Here we are asking `for` command to read each of the lines in the file and, for each one, split/tokenize the line using spaces as delimiters (default behaviour). Then, the `tokens=2,*` clause indicates that from all the possible tokens in the line, we want the second one and all the remaining elements in the line. That second token will be placed in the first available replaceable parameter, that is, the indicated in the `for` line, so, in our case, `%%a`. The rest of the line will be placed in the next one, so `%%b` will hold the rest of the data in the line.

So, `%%a` will hold the string `name` (from "Printer name") and `%%b` will hold the name of the printer.

With the name of the printer, `Prnmgr.vbs` is called to remove (`-d`) the printer (`-p`) indicated

Comment: Thanks!  That definitely helps my problem!  It didn't work out the gate, but while I can just use your code wholesale, if you're free, can you explain what %%a, -d, and "%%b" indicate? [Or a place where I can see some reference regarding this?] [I'm sorry, I was thrown a bit into the deep end with this assignment.]

Comment: @PtmD, `-d` is just a switch for `prnmngr.vbs`, if you run this file without arguments, you will see the help. I've added `%%a` and `%%b` information in answer and corrected a missing switch.

Comment: Awesome, you're a lifesaver!

While this doesn't work out the gate, I think this is everything I need to solve the issue.